# Print the content of all the files in the newest directory in BASH

Tags: bash, printing

I need to print in BASH the content of all the files that are inside the newest sub_directory and do it in one line.
How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "read"?  Do you just want a list of their names?

Comment: Related: BashFAQ #3 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: Only difference between this and the question it's duplicative of is that this one is looking for mtime rather than atime -- but that actually makes it easier; one can use `%T@` rather than `%A@` in the `find`-based answers.